# How can I select a generated title tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, drupal-7, raphael

I'm working on a SVG map (Raphael) on a Drupal site, and for some reason beyond me I can't get jQuery to affect the SVG map at all. I want to manipulate the `<a>` and its child (a path) using the `title="skane"` value as an anchor.

One weird thing is that when looking at the generated Raphael code in the inspector it says `title="skane"`, but if i copy the entire block to jsFiddle I get `xlink:title="skane"` – what's up with that?

In a Fiddle it seems to be working just fine using `$("a[xlink\\:title=skane]").hide();` but when I try to incorporate it into my script it doesn't do anything, even when entered in the console well after page load.

If I target all `<a>` tags with `$('a').hide();` the whole map disappears as expected, so how do I select only the `<a>` with `title="skane"`?

[Link to jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/lennyekberg/jvoq9b7n/)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your Fiddle just shows an `<a>` element with the attribute `xlink:title`, so it doesn't really help for finding a solution.

Comment: As I said: "_the generated Raphael code in the inspector it says title="skane", but if i copy the entire block to jsFiddle I get xlink:title="skane"_". Is that to be expected? I've never noticed that before at least.

Comment: You should have presented a running example with Raphael instead of the copied output of your experienced bug.

Comment: Yeah, while I agree that would have been optimal it would require a lot of work to break it out from the rest of the code to solve what I was hoping would be a minor issue. I might update the Fiddle tomorrow if there's no help to be found until then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$("a[title='skane']").hide();`?

Comment: Yeah, It just comes back with `[]` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. However I am not sure if that´s what you need.

```
var parameters = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    var attribs = parameters[i].attributes;
    for (var j = 0; j < attribs.length; j++) {

        if (attribs[j].localName == "xlink:title" && attribs[j].value == "skane") {
            parameters[i].style.display='none';
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: Your solution does indeed work when using it on jsfiddle, but running it in the console on the live site comes back with undefined in the console so there seems to be some kind of interference along the way somehow (I haven't actually deployed the code properly yet though as I'm away from my workstation). However if I do get it to work, it still seems to me like there should be a simpler solution out there (not taking anything away from your work of course!)